# How do I pass Variants as props to React Components in ReasonML?

Tags: reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I have tried the following approach to be able to send variants as props.

```
type ipAddr =
  | IPV4
  | IPV8;


[@react.component]
let make = () => {
  let appData = Data.tileData;
  <div className="App">
    <header className="flex outline justify-between" />
    <Content selected={ipAddr.IPV4} appData />
  </div>;
};
```

But it throws the error,

> ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed

I have tried sending variants directly to Component as well.

```
  <div className="App">
    <header className="flex outline justify-between" />
    <Content selected=IPV4 appData />
  </div>;
```

But it ended up returning another error

> Start compiling  ninja: error: dependency cycle: src/App-ReactHooksTemplate.cmj -> src/Content-ReactHooksTemplate.cmj
>   -> src/App-ReactHooksTemplate.cmj
>   Finish compiling(exit: 1)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try re-running the second version after cleaning the build — `npx bsb -clean-world && npx bsb -make-world`— and pasting *all* of the command output to gist.github.com or something like that. As far as I can tell, this should work, as presented in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this another way. Instead of passing the variant as prop, I simply rendered different components based on variant value.

```
[@react.component]
let make = () => {
  let appData = Data.tileData;
  switch (selected) {
  | IPV4 =>
    <div>
      <IPV4Renderer appData />
    </div>
  | IPV6 =>
    <div>
      <IPV6Renderer appData />
    </div>
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: I don't know ReasonML, *however*

If it was OCaml, you'd just write `IPV4`, no need to qualify it like `ipAddr.IPV4`.
Perhaps this is the same in Reason?

Comment: Yeah it would be just IPV4

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. But i tried it already and updated question to reflect the same.

Comment: If `Content` is in a separate file and refers to `ipAddr` in this module, that would be a dependency cycle since the modules refer to each other, which they're not allowed to. You need to either move `ipAddr` to `Content` or to a separate module that both this module and `Content` can refer to.

Comment: As mentioned, this was not a case of failed imports.